# how to change the wordpress theme css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors, atag

I have a problem with my wordpress theme. an web developer has customised the theme. Now i want to edit this theme, aspecially the <a  tag. so I did;

I edit the extra CSS inside my theme with;

```
#a{
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

#a:link{
  color:#4c4c4c;
}

#a:visited{
  color:#4c4c4c;
}

#a:hover{
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

#a:active{
  color: #4c4c4c;
}

#a:focus{
  color:#4c4c4c;
}
```

the hover color that this developer has changed has now go to the #4c4c4c color. but the color when you're no hovering is still the color this developer has set.

do anyone knows how i can change this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't address `<a>` tags using `#a { ... }` as a selector – `#a` would be the selector for an element that has "a" as its *ID* , like `<p id="a">...`.

Links are simply addressed via `a:link { ... }` in CSS, and all other variants (:visited, :hover, :active, :focus)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
#a{
  color: #4c4c4c !important;
}
```

The `! important` property in CSS means that all subsequent rules on an element are to be ignored, and the rule denoted by `! important` is to be applied. This rule overrides all previous styling rules ​-- the `! important` property increases its priority.